# Is it possible to format a date field? In knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm an beginner, and I would like to know if it is possible to format a field of type date? In knockout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knockout.js format date item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148572/knockout-js-format-date-item)

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to try [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/).

Download the moment.js file, include a  reference to it in your HTML file, for example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourPath/moment.js"></script>
```

More info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739568/how-do-i-link-a-javascript-file-to-a-html-file). Then you can use a text binding to call moment from a span or a text box to format your date string like so:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="text: moment(yourDateVariable).format('DD MMM YY')"></input>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148572/knockout-js-format-date-item) is another good thread with some answers, hope this helps.

Comment: Doing this breaks two way binding.